# Stopping thread of log4J AsyncAppender

Tags: java, thread-safety, log4j

I'm using Log4J AsyncAppender in my application and I wonder, what happens with the AsyncAppender's thread when my application finishes? Should I terminate the thread manually or can I just forget about it and exit from my application without worrying that some log messages will be lost?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `LogManager.shutdown()` before the JVM shuts down, it will continue to run until the appenders have been flushed. Note that this is only necessary for log4j 1.x.  I understand from documentation that Log4j 2 automatically registers a shutdown hook to handle this.

Comment: That's the only I manage to get all the logs when shutting down a short live application with asyncAppender and RollingRandomAccessFile *without* immediate flush, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of AsyncAppender, [it creates a daemon thread](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.java?view=markup) (lines 112-117) to handle the writing the events, and the authors expect you explicitly call `close()` on the appender to ensure that any queued messages are written out before the JVM shuts down:

```
dispatcher = new Thread(new Dispatcher(this, buffer, discardMap, appenders));

// It is the user's responsibility to close appenders before
// exiting.
dispatcher.setDaemon(true);
```

By setting the thread as a daemon, it means that the JVM will not keep running once the core of your application exits. However, this also means that if your application shuts down without notifying the appender, any messages in the queue would be lost.

Comment: How can I get access to the appender object if I'm configuring log4J using xml and I'm using slf4J and spring? Is there some way that I could configure log4J in the xml to automatically call the appender's close method when the app is closing?

Comment: That's a good question as it seems like a pretty confusing part of their API (and makes the design decision to require a call to `close()` confusing). I'm not sure what the best way to be access the appender would be, but you could try something like `Logger.getLogger(name).getAllAppenders()` or `Logger.getLogger(name).getAppender(name)` or `Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders()`. I'd add this in a JVM shutdown hook. It wouldn't be pretty as it requires your app code to know the logging config

Answer (score 0):

If the AsyncAppender is a thread running within your application, it will be closed when you close your application (and by application I mean the current instance of the jvm). I don't know if that is your question however

Comment: this isn't very accurate - a non-daemon thread would keep running and would keep the JVM from shutting down.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to try to make it more clear and accurate